# I get NA when using as.Date in r

Tags: r, as.date

When I use the "as.Date" command in r it returns Na as a result, I have tried different things like transforming it to POSIXt format, changing the date format with % and even using the "paste" command, but it doesn't work.

```
    #The format I want to have: 
    format(Sys.Date(), "%B de %Y")
    [1] "December de 2022"

    #Example
    date="noviembre de 2022"

    #Attempt 1:
    date2 <- strptime(date, format = "%B de %Y")
    date3 <- as.Date(date2,format="%B de %Y")
    date3
    [1] NA

    #Attempt 2:
    date2 <- as.Date(paste(1, gsub("de ", "", date)), format = "%d %B %Y")
    date2
    [1] NA

    #Attempt 3:
    date2 <- as.Date(date,format="%B de %Y")
    date2
    [1] NA

    #Attempt 4:
    a <- as.character("noviembre de 2022")
    pos_dt <- strptime(a, format = "%B de %Y")
    b <- as.Date(pos_dt, format = "%B de %Y")
    print(a)
    [1] NA
    print(b)
    [1] NA
```

I don't know what other option I could try or how I could solve the problem. I just need r to read me the date format like I have in the example.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Date objects require a day, month and year. You have only a month and a year.

Comment: The `zoo` package has a `yearmon` type and the `tsibble` package has the `yearmonth` type, perhaps those would be more helpful for you if you don't want to specify a specific Date, which specifies one day, so it needs you to pick a day.